# Function inside an if statement inside a function

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following code:

```
function someFunctionThatRunsOnce(identifier){
    if (var < 1){
        runSomeOtherFunction(identifier);
        var++;
    }
}
```

The variable will not increment when var < 1 is true.  It stays at 0 and does not increase.  When I move the variable increment statement about runSomeOtherFunction(), it then works fine.

What I want to know is:
1) Why is this happening?  Why is running the second function disabling the increment?
2) Is there a better way to do this?  I need to run this function this way exactly once, under a set of very specific circumstances.  The function that runs is used elsewhere using different parameters for (identifier).

Please keep things simple I am a super noob and do not know jQuery and only really simple use of JS.

Comment: Please show your actual code or a complete example that displays the problem. The code you have shown does not behave the way that you have described.

Comment: Actually that is exactly how it looks.  And it works if I reverse the 3rd and 4th lines.  This is simpler.

Comment: If calling a function causes problems in your code, **we need to see what's in that function**. Otherwise it's impossible to say what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

a big issue is that "var" is not a valid variable name, it's a reserved keyword.

you can easily use your wrapper as a namespace to store the state of being called or not:

```
function someFunctionThatRunsOnce(identifier){
    if (!someFunctionThatRunsOnce.spent){ //not run yet?
        someFunctionThatRunsOnce.spent=true; //set as run
        runSomeOtherFunction(identifier); //run real workload
    }
}
```

this lets you avoid global variables and curtails the possibility of runSomeOtherFunction() accidentally changing the state of the spent tracker property.